# Does DynamoDB charge for the table deletion?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I need to delete most items from a large table (billions of entries) in DynamoDB.

My two options are to delete the entire table or do a scan and therefore delete in batches. This second option counts as read/write capacity. But I would like to know if deleting the entire table at once charges me as write capacity of DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html)

The following describes how DynamoDB write operations consume `write capacity units`:

- PutItem
- UpdateItem
- DeleteItem
- BatchWriteItem

The following describes how DynamoDB read operations consume `read capacity units`:

- GetItem
- BatchGetItem
- Query
- Scan

To [delete table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteTable.html) you need to use `DeleteTable`, which is not in the list of `read` or `write` operations. It doesn't count as `capacity unit` consuming operation, therefore it shouldn't be charged.

Answer (score 1):

There is no charge for deleting a table. I opened a bug with the docs team to add this info to the documentation.